# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 7 on a binary search

Tags: java, binary-search

I have to write a program for search the correspondent of "Nomi" by entering the "Prezzo" value, but when I do the binary search, I get the error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 7 on a binary search

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Blackfriday {
    public static int ricercaBinaria(Double prezzi[], Double chiave) {
        int inf = 0, sup = prezzi.length - 1;
        while (inf <= sup) {
            int med = (inf + sup) / 2;
            if (prezzi[med] == chiave)
                return med;
            if (prezzi[med] < chiave)
                inf = med + 1;
            else
                sup = med - 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            InputStreamReader isr;
            BufferedReader br;
            double cerca;
            isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);// abilitato la lettura da tastiera
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);// abilitato la lettura un rigo per volta
            String nomi[] = { "picones", "vinile di Speranza", "Laurea", "King Mufasa", "Pentium Gold",
                    "Aethey Wind breaker ORO", "HeelCompletoSpaic1we" };
            Double prezzi[] = { 2.0, 13.50, 23.0, 99.50, 120.0, 75.20, 999.99 };
            System.out.println("Quanto vuoi spendere?");
            String xStringa = br.readLine();// ricevo la digitazione in String
            cerca = Double.parseDouble(xStringa);// Trasformo la String in double
            System.out.println("Puoi comprare: " + nomi[ricercaBinaria(prezzi, cerca)]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a functioning code :

1. Always display the stackTrace in case of Exception catch, it will help for the debug
2. if you manage Objects "Double" and try to compare them with ==, it will compare their reference (address in memory) and not the value contained inside of them. So use simple type double OR compare objects with equals() method.

```
public class Blackfriday {
    public static int ricercaBinaria(double prezzi[], Double chiave) {
        int inf = 0, sup = prezzi.length - 1;
        while (inf <= sup) {
            int med = (inf + sup) / 2;
            if (prezzi[med] == chiave)
                return med;
            if (prezzi[med] < chiave)
                inf = med + 1;
            else
                sup = med - 1;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            InputStreamReader isr;
            BufferedReader br;
            double cerca;
            isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);//abilitato la lettura da tastiera
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);//abilitato la lettura un rigo per volta
            String nomi[] = {"picones", "vinile di Speranza", "Laurea", "King Mufasa", "Pentium Gold", "Aethey Wind breaker ORO", "HeelCompletoSpaic1we"};
            double prezzi[] = {2.0, 13.50, 23.0, 99.50, 120.0, 75.20, 999.99};
            System.out.println("Quanto vuoi spendere?");
            String xStringa = br.readLine();//ricevo la digitazione in String
            cerca = Double.parseDouble(xStringa);//Trasformo la String in double
            System.out.println("Puoi comprare: " + nomi[ricercaBinaria(prezzi, cerca)]);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//main
}//classe
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two problems with your code.

1. A precondition of `ricercaBinaria` is that the underlying data array is ordered. You are using unordered data in your test
2. `ricercaBinaria` will return the index in which a given argument (`Double`) is located in your array. If it is not found, then `-1` will be returned. As such, you need to check the returned index to verify that it is indeed positive before using it as an index array - otherwise the method will fail with the exception you are seeing
3. Beware of Double equality but that is for another question.

Comment: i had no idea that the array must be ordered, thanks you so much!!